# ios-sim stopped working "NSCFString containsString" error

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-simulator, ionic-framework

I'm using [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com) to build a hybrid mobile app. Previously I've had no trouble launching the emulator via "ionic emulate ios" command. But all of a sudden the command started throwing errors.

I've tried removing then adding back the ios platform, uninstalling then re-installing ios-sim, but still get the same error message below. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

```html
2015-06-13 14:06:20.198 ios-sim[12997:507] -[__NSCFString containsString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f98e06006e0
2015-06-13 14:06:20.200 ios-sim[12997:507] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString containsString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f98e06006e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9303925c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9058ee75 objc_exception_throw + 43
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9303c12d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92f97272 ___forwarding___ + 1010
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92f96df8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
 5   ios-sim                             0x0000000107511534 -[iPhoneSimulator runWithArgc:argv:] + 1313
 6   ios-sim                             0x0000000107511e79 main + 101
 7   ios-sim                             0x000000010750f0e0 start + 52
 8   ???                                 0x000000000000000a 0x0 + 10
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: What version of iOS are you running it on? `containsString:` was added in iOS 8, so it will crash with that error if you try to call it on iOS 7.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer...any thoughts on how to check the iOS version Ionic uses?

Comment: The iOS version doesn't matter.  What is the host OS version that you're running on.  It was added in OS X 10.10.If you're running on Mavericks (OS X 10.9), that looks like a bug in ios-sim.

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.9. What's weird though is that I had no issues before. It just all of a sudden stopped working. Are there any alternatives to ios-sim? Thanks guys for all the help

Answer (score 0):

What version of ios-sim are you using? (Run `ios-sim --version` to find out.)

The `containsString` crash on Mavericks is caused by [this bug](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim/issues/170), which exists in [v3.2.0](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim/releases/tag/3.2.0) (see [here](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim/blob/3.2.0/Source/iPhoneSimulator.m#L710)).

If you downgrade to [v3.1.1](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim/releases/tag/3.1.1), or upgrade to [v4.1.1](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim/releases/tag/4.1.1), then ios-sim should work fine on Mavericks.